# How to format xml created from XML::LibXML in perl

Tags: perl

I am creating XML data in Perl by using XML::LibXML Module But when i am writing the data into a file want to Pretty-printing it so that is it can be easily readable .

Below is a snapshot how i am creating xml from my perl script:

```
my $xml = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->createElement('A');
$elem->setAttribute('B',data)
```

Is there any way we can format the XML by using XML::LibXML because i have to stick with this module only.

Comment: What do you mean by 'format'? Pretty-printing ?

Comment: @collapsar yes that's what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`XML::LibXML::Document::serialize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod#serialize) writes the xml document as text. Its parameter allows for limited control over the format of the output.

`XML::LibXML` is a veneer to the `libxml2` system library. This library comes with a hard-coded indentation of 2 spaces, so unless you create your own pretty-printer your options will be limited.

However, there are a number of standalone utilities that reformat syntactically valid xml and allow more fine-grained control and which can be run as a postprocessor from within perl on a file with the serialized xml. I've been satisfied with `xmlstarlet` and `xmllint`.

Another question is whether you really want to invest many resources into the endeavour. If you need the human-readable version for debugging or out-of-order inspection only, loading the data into a browser like Chrome or Firefox may be enough - they run xml data through a very decent pretty-printer.